# How do I check if the name of some file matches some pattern (has "SSS" in it, for example) in `if` clause?

Tags: shell, regex

How do I check if the name of some file matches some pattern (has "SSS" in it, for example) in `if` clause? My variant does not seem to work (it is always false).

```
for f in B/* ; do
    if [ $f = .*SSS.* ] ; then
#    if [ -f $f ] -and -regex ".*SSS.*"; then
        echo $f
    fi
done
```

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: MATE Terminal 1.16.1.

Comment: That's not a shell. I mean like bash, or tcsh or ksh.

Comment: Probably bash. How to come to know?

Answer (score 1):

You need double brackets, and no '.' (Shell globbing no sed regex)

```
for f in B/* ; do
    if [[ $f = *SSS* ]] ; then
        echo $f
    fi
done
```

A bit of google gives you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348379/use-regular-expression-in-if-condition-in-bash